# User Defined Functions in Presto

Tags: presto

I am currently working with Presto 0.80. I have to write a user defined function to convert degree celsius to degree fahrenheit during select query. I did the same using Hive QL but was wondering if we can replicate the same in Facebook Presto.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a guide for writing a new function in presto.
https://trino.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html

After writing your function, add the plugin to the `plugin` directory as explained in [SPI Overview](https://trino.io/docs/current/develop/spi-overview.html).

There is another example for writing presto UDF from Qubole blog.
http://www.qubole.com/blog/product/plugging-in-presto-udfs/
You can try it if you can make it work.

Comment: The whole point of SPI is that you should dont need to recompile presto-main.  You just build a jar which has your Plugin class name in META-INF/services, drop it in the plugin directory and restart the cluster

Comment: Compiling Presto UDFs from the Qubole blog worked for me! Thanks!