# Presto - How can i filter array values that are occurring consecutively

Tags: arrays, presto

I want to filter out the values from an array that are occurring consecutively.

I tried using the "array_distinct" & "transform" function in presto, but couldn't progress. As array_distinct only gives distinct values not what i expect

```
Input : [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,2]
```

Expected Output : [1,2,3,4,2]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inspect consecutive elements by combining `ngrams`, `filter`, `transform`, like this:

```
presto> SELECT
     ->     ARRAY[a[1]] ||
     ->     transform(
     ->         filter(
     ->             ngrams(a, 2),
     ->             pair -> pair[1] IS DISTINCT FROM pair[2]),
     ->         pair -> pair[2])
     -> FROM (VALUES ARRAY[1,2,2,3,4,4,4,2]) t(a);
      _col0
-----------------
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
(1 row)
```

Explanation:

- `ngrams(a, 2)` builds sibling pairs
- `filter` is then used to retain only the elements that are not proceeded by identical one; `IS DISTINCT FROM` is used for more `NULL`-friendly comparison that ordinary `=`.
- `transform` is used to convert from siblings back to flat array
- first element is added at the front (otherwise it would be always missing)

See https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html for all array functions available.

Answer (score 1):

I think there won't be any direct function available.
You can write a custom UDF for the logic.

https://geeks.jampp.com/data-infrastructure/technology/writing-custom-presto-functions/

https://www.qubole.com/blog/plugging-in-presto-udfs/

[User Defined Functions in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472534)

Here is the algorithm:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-consecutive-duplicates-from-list/